# How to remove rows where all numerical columns contain zero in Pandas Dataframe with mixed type of columns?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following data frame:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[0,0,1,1], 'b':[0,1,0,1],'tag':['apple','orange','grapes','lemon']})
df = df[["tag","a","b"]]
```

That looks like this:

```
In [37]: df
Out[37]:
      tag  a  b
0   apple  0  0
1  orange  0  1
2  grapes  1  0
3   lemon  1  1
```

What I want to do is to remove rows where numerical columns is zero resulting in this:

```
tag     a  b
orange  0  1
grapes  1  0
lemon   1  1
```

How can I achieve that?

Note that in actuality, the number of columns can be more than 2 and column name can be varied. So we need a general solution.

I tried this but has no effect:

```
df[(df.T != 0).any()]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a few different things going on in this answer, let me know if anything is particularly confusing:

```
df.loc[~ (df.select_dtypes(include=['number']) == 0).all(axis='columns'), :]
```

So:

- Filtering to find just the numeric columns
- Applying the `.all()` method across columns rather than rows (rows is the default)
- Negating with `~`
- Passing the resulting boolean series to `df.loc[]`

Answer (score 1):

Get numeric columns:

```
numcols = df.dtypes == np.int64
```

create indexer

```
   I =  np.sum((df.loc[:,numcols]) != 0,axis = 1) != 0


   df[I]

      tag  a  b
1  orange  0  1
2  grapes  1  0
3   lemon  1  1
```

Comment: I need a general solution, not tight to column name or number of columns.

Comment: edited to give you a general solution (not the prettiest)

Comment: I think just checking against `int64` is too specific, you want to include all float/int types.

Comment: yeah i like your answer better, i've never seen `select_dtypes` before